# Set App Entry point programmatically in AppDelegate

Tags: ios, swift, startup, appdelegate, entry-point

In my appdelegate I want to check if `globUs.hasName`.  If it does I want the `Entry Point` of the app to be my `main` storyboard.  If it does not I want the `Entry Point` of the app to be my `newUser` storyboard.  How do I set the entry point of the app?  If I can't, what is the most effective way to implement this functionality?

Comment: just set the self.window?.rootViewController as your preferred viewController in didFinishLaunchingWithOptions function.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Consider not having an entry point. Then, in appDelegate, test for your variable and choose the appropriate storyboard accordingly. Then show the view controller from that storyboard.

```
func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplicationLaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {

    if globUs.hasName {
        let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
        let vc = storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "FirstMainVC")
        self.window = UIWindow(frame: UIScreen.main.bounds)
        self.window?.rootViewController = new
        self.window?.makeKeyAndVisible()
    }
    else {
        let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "NewUser", bundle: nil)
        let vc = storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "FirstNewUserVC")
        self.window = UIWindow(frame: UIScreen.main.bounds)
        self.window?.rootViewController = welcomeVC
        self.window?.makeKeyAndVisible()
    }

    return true
}
```

Comment: When I use a method similar to this AppDel throws a SIGABRT.  It says that "'Could not find a storyboard named 'OneStoryboard' in bundle NSBundle </Users/gabrielspound/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/6CB76037-BA27-45DA-8671-01AAF78E93A6/data/Containers/Bundle/Application/0B5AC724-BEF5-4DB6-A68F-8407A6ECF627/Social Justice.app> (loaded)'"
What does the "name:" field mean in the UIStoryboard constructor?  Is it arbitrary or do I have to use the filename of my Main.storyboard?

Comment: @GabeSpound Yes, you are using the filename

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
var sb = UIStoryboard(name: "OneStoryboard", bundle: nil)
/// Load initial view controller
var vc = sb.instantiateInitialViewController()
/// Or load with identifier
var vc = instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "foobarViewController")

/// Set root window and make key and visible
self.window = UIWindow(frame: UIScreen.mainScreen.bounds)
self.window.rootViewController = vc
self.window.makeKeyAndVisible()
```

Or try manual segue in storyboard. To perform manual segue, you have to first define a segue with identifier in storyboard and then call `performSegue(withIdentifier:sender:)` in view controller.

Comment: Check the comment I left for the answer above, it pertains here as well.

Comment: I got this working, but the other method seems more effective